# send email with attachment javascript

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, email-attachments

I would like to send email with attachment by using activex on IE.
I want to add an element such as img or canvas from my page. How can I do that? Here is some code.

```
var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
var objO = new ActiveXObject('Outlook.Application');     
mItm.Attachments.Add(); // can add img??
```

Thank you very much for your helps.

Comment: There may be a way to send the attachment, but I don't think you're going to be able to access that ActiveX object from a web page. At the very least it will require configuring the site to be in the correct domain and/or making the browser insecure for all sites.